# Can't build gcc anymore since upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, application-development, compiling, gcc

On Monday I've upgraded to from Ubuntu 11.04 (my initial installation) to 11.10 and now I can't build gcc from source anymore. Since I forgot to uninstall the gcc package before the upgrade, Ubuntu replaced my 4.7.0 compiler with it's stable 4.6.1. So I tried to build the SVN sources again, but it fails. I've most recently tried it with SVN revision 180193.

After some time, the build fails with the following message:

```
/home/raphael/devel/gcc/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/raphael/devel/gcc/build/./gcc/ -B/usr/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/i686-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/i686-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/i686-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include    -g -O2 -O2  -I. -I. -I../../src/gcc -I../../src/gcc/. -I../../src/gcc/../include -I../../src/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../src/gcc/../libdecnumber/bid -I../libdecnumber -I../../src/gcc/../libgcc -g -O2 -DIN_GCC   -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition  -isystem ./include  -fPIC -g -DHAVE_GTHR_DEFAULT -DIN_LIBGCC2 -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector   -I. -I. -I../.././gcc -I../../../src/libgcc -I../../../src/libgcc/. -I../../../src/libgcc/../gcc -I../../../src/libgcc/../include -I../../../src/libgcc/config/libbid -DENABLE_DECIMAL_BID_FORMAT -DHAVE_CC_TLS  -DUSE_TLS -o _ashldi3.o -MT _ashldi3.o -MD -MP -MF _ashldi3.dep -DL_ashldi3 -c ../../../src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c \
    -fvisibility=hidden -DHIDE_EXPORTS
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,
             from ../../../src/libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:88,
             from ../../../src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:29:
/usr/include/features.h:323:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: File or directory not found.
```

I've cofigured it with:

```
~/devel/gcc/build$ ../src/configure --prefix=/usr --enable-languages=c++
```

And make it with:

```
~/devel/gcc/build$ make -j4
```

Just to be sure, I did a `rm -rf *`  in the build directory in case there's some broken stuff inside. Didn't help, though.

---

That's the backstory. I tried to fix it and searched for the `bits/predefs.h`. It's inside `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu`. I temporarily fixed the problem by doing

```
~/devel/gcc/build$ C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu make -j4
```

Which is only temporary because now gcc complains that it can't find `crti.o`.

Which i can find in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`. <strike>Now i *could* also set `C_LIBRARY_PATH`</strike> - actually it doesn't work - but I feel like I'm fighting the system here. Also, even if it succeeds, my newly built compiler would also not know about the `i386-linux-gnu` stuff. So I would have to set `C_LIBRARY_PATH` and `C_INCLUDE_PATH` before every build of every project I have. I *could* add it to my .bashrc but that subverts the system *even more*.

So, how do I tell the build process:

- That there are additional include/lib directories, and
- That it should build a gcc which respects them too?

---

*Edit:* I forgot to include the command which causes the above error message. Also I can think of another solution: Copy the stuff from `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu` to `/usr/include` (same thing for `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` to `/usr/lib`). But that doesn't feel right, either. Finally, the system's gcc 4.6.1 can compile other applications just fine, except mine, which use C++11 features not present in the 4.6 series.

Comment: +1: I can't compile gcc trunk with the error-msg: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory. Figuring out the correct configure-command is particularly painful, since it takes 20 minutes before the compile breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply this patch, and configure with --enable-multiarch (not to be confused with multi*lib*):

- http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2011-08/msg01674.html

<sup>(That supersedes [this earlier patch](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2011-08/msg01649.html).)</sup>

Comment: And, if you don't like patching your sources, and setting flags aren't working for you, just soft-link crt*.o into the /usr/lib dirctory (you'll find them in either /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu or /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu).

Comment: I'm using Debian now so I can't check whether it works, but it looks OK so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Some more material at:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=644986

Rather than using the whole script, the key part seems to be:

```
make FLAGS_FOR_TARGET="-B/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu"
```

The result is not entirely clean because it still needs a wrapper script after installation to execute with the right additional options. For example here is the example from the article /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 :

```
#!/bin/sh

exec /opt/gcc-4.7/bin/gcc-4.7 -B/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 11.10 brings multi-arch support which means that you shouldn't put library files in `/usr/lib` but `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` (32-bit) or `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (64-bit).

Use something like:

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu ./configure [options]
```

You probably need to specify `LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` too.

Aside: your paths do not look pretty: `/usr/i686-pc-linux-gnu/lib/`, you might want to use options like `--libdir` to correct it.

Comment: It was actually added in 11.04, but 11.10 was when things were complete.

Comment: Hmmm. The CFLAGS work, but if I set LDFLAGS it still can't find the crti.o . Also, the LDFLAGS don't appear in the command which links the libgcc_s.so . Then I added the -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu to the CFLAGS. Now it appears in the command, but it STILL can't find it. I double-checked the path. It looks like gcc doesn't look at the -L paths when searching for .o files.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Perhaps it's the scripts used for building `gcc` on Ubuntu show what you need (`apt-get source --diff-only gcc`, then run `tar xf ...` if it's a tarball and `patch -p0 < ...` if it's a diff file)

Answer (score 1):

Since your building from SVN, are you sure your building from the same revision? AKA, make sure the issue isn't upstream :-)

Comment: We are most likely not building from the same revision. We are unable to figure out reasonable ./configure command-options to complete a build with the new multiarch layout of Debian/Ubuntu.